# From QM to QFT learning approach

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-field-theory, field-theory, resource-recommendations, second-quantization

The passage from the undergraduated course of quantum mechanics and the first course of qft was plenty traumatic: usual concepts like the hamiltonian of a system with its energy eigenstates, orbital angular momentum, the uncertainty principle and so on seemed to me vanished in this new framework. Moreover, some unanswered questions from the undergraduated course like the decay of an excited electron into the ground state with a photon emission still remained obscure. During the past months I was able to link something, but it's more like of having a big hole from the last section of NRQM and the quantization of fields. Furthermore, our QFT courses mostly focussed on scattering theory and renormalization, which is good, but left so many topics behind. So what I'm asking you is if there is a book, or a collection of books to follow for closing all these gaps in my knowledge. I know that this sounds like the nth-related post on QFT books, but I tryed many of them and they seems all so "self referenced". For example, Maggiore is like a short summary of the state of the art, Srednicki is good if you need to check something but you dont need to go deep, Schwartz seems to have forget what does it mean to learn from zero this subject; Zee offers some hint, but it misses this "bridge"-like behaviour which I'm asking. The only relevant book I think it's made for that purpose is Weinberg, but for a newcomer it seems rally unreadable with all that ugly and gory notation. Hoping to get answers and good advices and that this post will be useful for people like me who are trying to understand QFT beyond the LSZ formula.

Edit: so as far as I can understand, first of all I have to go through a good book of RQM which doesnt simply show me all types of relativistic eqs. Then I should turn to the first 5 chapters of Weinberg and "lose" time over them to get solid foundations. Then I can go for I&Z to get the feeling of the qft mindset. Given those, I should be able to appreciate better the books I have cited. If anybody else wants to share his/her experience it would be appreciated and welcomed.

Comment: Strange that you left out Peskin and Schroeder, which may address some of your concerns. You may also try the lectures by Sidney Coleman.

Comment: I'll post this as a comment rather than an answer because it is really about what worked for me. And by the end of your post you may not like it but the only thing that really worked for me was to go through the first 5 chapters of Weinberg's textbook. After that the other ones started making a whole lot more sense and I was able to appreciate books like the one by Schwartz and Peskin & Schroeder. Weinberg is hard and notation is really an issue, but in my opinion (and that's why this is a comment) it's *extremely* worthwhile studying it.

Comment: The first chapter or so of Itzykson and Zuber (an old book that's out of date in many areas but still very good at the topics it covers) goes through a few examples applying QFT-type-thinking to "ordinary undergraduate problems", like how a photon counter works. I highly recommend it. It also has a chapter on treating the hydrogen atom in QFT, which is something a lot of modern books don't do. As an additional remark... there's an educational shift that happens in grad school from "learning general physics" to "getting up to speed on research physics," which IMO can lead to some gaps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your curriculum committee was evidently complacent.
The gap is only there if you fail to take the bridge course **after** your QM course.

Generations, including mine, had that gap filled by J J Sakurai's classic *Advanced quantum mechanics* ISBN-13: ‎ 978-8177589160 . The book  shows you the nuts & bolts   *behind* all this  pompous/abstract verbiage of QFT, and speaks the language of the generation that invented the stuff.

Also the 1964 classic *Relativistic Quantum Mechanics*, (junior partner to the much more famous QFT sequel  "v II") by  J Bjorken and S Drell.  Generations of teachers knew it by heart, and *assumed* everybody did, so they skipped words, a habit picked up by those who wrote subsequent QFT texts.

Comment: Oh yes I see what you mean by scrolling the index of these books. Actually, we got a course on RQM but it was something like "ok this is Klein-Gordon lagrangian, equation, current, symmetries and stuff like that. Now turn to Dirac, this is the lagrangian, equation, and so on..." so it really didn't make the bridge, in the sense that it didn't tell you where is the usual QM "hidden" behind QFT. Schwarz says that "QFT is QM with a lot of fields", but it is hard for me to spot all the ingredients which I was used to be exposed before introducing fields.

Comment: If your course covered the [repackaging of field normal mode oscillators](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phonon#One-dimensional_lattice)  at the classical level and then their *trivial* quantization, fine. If not, they cheated you!

Comment: Gonna try the Sakurai book

Comment: grateful thanks for suggesting me Sakurai. It really helped me to cover so many "transition topics" and I loved so much how it goes through second quantization in the most simple, clear and crude way.

Answer (score 1):

From my point of view, i.e as a graduate student still studying QFT, what you are experiencing is comepletely normal - in the sense that you cannot expect to get a full understanding of QFT and its relation with QM on your first course. I think you will even realize (to me at least it seemed so) that even from the QM point of view alone, your undergraduate course isn't enough as a basis for a true understanding of QFT, a much more profound knowledge of QM is necessary for QFT. It is safe to say (at least to me) that those gaps you talk about maybe won't be filled at your first approacch to QFT. To me it's a learning process that is still going on, where with time and patience different pieces comes togheter. The best approach to me is what you are doing, following your classes and get some more informations from textbooks.

Some books  which I used for specific topics are the following (the main path was given by my professor's lectures). During my first approach I used Maggiore, and Mandl and Shaw, which gave me a general understanding of QFT and some tools for calculations and physical understanding. Then I used for specific topics Weinberg (es all chapter 2) and Peskin. A big step to get a sense of QFT to me is truly understanding the LSZ reduction formula, and according to my professor this is well done in the original paper and in Bjorken and Drell (we mainly follower their approach).

Another helpfull resource are the lecture notes by Timo Weigand, these to me are great as an introduction. On more advanced topics I am using Cheng and Lee book which seems really good (But not as an introduction) and other books for specific arguments like Strocchi's work on SSB and non perturbative aspects, or Schwartz for aspects regarding the Standard model and its phenomenology. The point to me is not to focus on a single book, but on the arguments - try following your lectures using the textbooks that suit you as support, to get a better understanding. You will see that some textbooks explain better some things and pass on others, so mixing is fundamental to me. Slowly the formalism becomes clear and you start to see what kind of reasoning is proper in QFT, and from here there will be many questions that will spontaneously arise, leading to more formal aspects which helps understand the theory and its limits better.

Comment: Minor note: the original author of this CW post is @Ratman and not me